# Search for a reference on characterising Lebesgue spaces in terms of (inhomogeneous) Besov spaces.

Tags: sobolev-spaces, besov-space, littlewood-paley-theory

I am trying to find a proof that

$||f||_{L^{p}}\sim{}||f||_{B^0_{p,2}}$

where $||f||_{B^s_{p,r}}=||(2^{js}||f_j||_{L^p})_{j\in\mathrm{Z}_{\geq{}-1}}||_{\ell^r}$ is the norm characterising the inhomogeneous Besov space. (Here $f=\sum{}f_j$ is the Littlewood-Paley decomposition.) Any references would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't think this is true unless $p = 2$. You need to consider Triebel-Lizorkin spaces instead of Besov spaces.

Comment: Ah, thanks. Yes I found an article on the distinction - I can't swap the order of norms. Do you know of a counter example showing this to be false?